# Chrome Extension: Issue with Sending and Receiving Messages Between Background and Popup Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension and facing a problem with sending and receiving messages between my background script (`background.js`) and popup script (`popup.js`). The issue is that I can see the summary logged in the background script but not in the popup script. Additionally, I am unable to display the summary in the popup.

the (`console.log('Sending response with action "summarizePage" and summary:', summary);`) in (`background.js`) gives me the summary on console. But when the control goes back to

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
        console.log(response.action);
    if (response.action === "summaryResponse") {
       console.log('Received summary response:', response);
```

in `popup.js` , nothing is being printed on the console. I do not understand why and how to resolve this issue.

Here is the relevant code:

**background.js:**

```
const apiKey = 'xyz';

// Function to send a request for summarization
async function summarizePageContent(pageContent, sendResponse) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.cohere.ai/v1/summarize', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                text: pageContent, 
                length: 'medium',
                format: 'paragraph',
                model: 'command',
                extractiveness: 'low',
                temperature: 0.3,
            })
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            const summary = data.summary;
                        
            console.log('Sending response with action "summarizePage" and summary:', summary);

            sendResponse({ action: "summaryResponse", summary });
        } else {
            console.error('Error fetching data from API:', response.status);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.action === "pageContent") {
        const pageContent = request.content;
        summarizePageContent(pageContent, sendResponse);
    }
    return true;
});
```

**popup.js:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const summarizeButton = document.getElementById("summarizeButton");
    const summaryDiv = document.getElementById("summary");

    summarizeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "pageContent" });
    });
   
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
        console.log(response.action);
        if (response.action === "summaryResponse") {
            console.log('Received summary response:', response);
            if (response.summary) {
                summaryDiv.textContent = response.summary;
            } else {
                summaryDiv.textContent = "Error: Unable to summarize the page.";
            }
        } else if (response.action === "responseMessage") {
            console.log('Received response message:', response);
        }
    });
});
```

**content.js:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Extract the page content
    const pageContent = document.body.innerText;

    // Send the page content to the background script
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "pageContent", content: pageContent });
});
```

Comment: 1) Remove onMessage listener and see the first example in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) which shows how to receive a response. 2) You send the same `pageContent` message from the web page (in the content script) and from the extension popup, which doesn't make sense  because the popup isn't a web page. Maybe the goal is to send the text of the web page on demand? Then you don't need a content script, you can use executeScript ([example](/a/67227376)). There's also no need for the background script, just do everything in the popup.

Comment: Your reply was helpful. I got rid of the content.js. Ultimately only kept background.js and popup.js and added all the functions in these two only. I also avoided using onMessage, instead used javascript's onclick event listener.